# A question about local finite example in Munkres.

Tags: general-topology

> [image]

I don't understand, for $\mathcal B$, if I take $4 \in \mathbb{R}$, isn't the open set $(3/2, 5)$ intersecting only one element from $\mathcal B$?

Comment: B is not locally finite within R because of 0, not because of 4.

Comment: ah okay thanks!!